# Why am I getting the same value for echo $RANDOM for all iterations in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, random

bash script:

```
for c in $( seq 1 10) 
do
   echo "random value #$c:$(echo "$RANDOM")" 
done
```

output:

```
random value #1:20892
random value #2:20892
random value #3:20892
random value #4:20892
random value #5:20892
random value #6:20892
random value #7:20892
random value #8:20892
random value #9:20892
random value #10:20892
```

Comment: Exactly how are you invoking the script?  In other words, what is the command line that you use to run the script?

Comment: I can reproduce this with bash 4.3.8 only in this way: `for c in $( seq 1 10) ; do    echo "random value #$c:$(RANDOM=42; echo "$RANDOM")" ; done`

Comment: I think it was some old version of bash that I used. I couldn't use {1..10} in for loop therefore had to resort to seq. Although, I am not getting the error (getting different random values)now . I'm not sure what changed though. Anyways, it works now. That's all that matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using an old version of `bash`, there's absolutely *no* reason to resort to `seq` for generating that sequence of yours.

In addition, something like `echo $(echo something)` is *totally* unnecessary.

Changing the script for both those concerns:

```
for c in {1..10} ; do
   echo "random value #$c:$RANDOM"
done
```

gives you something that generates the correct data:

```
random value #1:3394
random value #2:6099
random value #3:21492
random value #4:17973
random value #5:22698
random value #6:15844
random value #7:28506
random value #8:1960
random value #9:23593
random value #10:17412
```

---

And, in actual fact, your *original* script also works (at least in `bash 4.3.46`) so I'm guessing you may have inadvertently stuffed up the `RANDOM` variable somewhere. You should be aware that unsetting that "variable" can cause issues with its use later on, and setting it to a specific value seeds the generator.

Hence I'd be looking for something in your `bash` per-shell startup scripts which possibly sets `RANDOM` to a specific value. Said script would be executed because of the `$(echo $RANDOM)` thing and may be fixed if you simply echo the value directly).

That would certainly cause your issue, as per the following demo:

```
for c in {1..5} ; do
    RANDOM=7
    echo "random value #$c:$RANDOM"
done
```

which gives:

```
random value #1:19345
random value #2:19345
random value #3:19345
random value #4:19345
random value #5:19345
```

Comment: I think it was some old version of bash that I used. I couldn't use {1..10} in for loop therefore had to resort to seq.

Comment: @amar, for a small sequence like that, you can just use `for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do ...`.